# multiple php on apache centos

Tags: php, apache, centos, fastcgi, phpfarm

How can I get multiple php versions running on Centos 6.5 at the same time ?

Here's how.

**Requirements**
Centos 6.5 (Possible works with 6.6 and 7) 
Apache   Apache/2.2.15 (Possible works with other versions)

**This guide installs and uses**
 
FASTCGI (see the comments for alternative installation)
PHPFARM
This install was done this way so it would be compatable with iredmail.
You can install iredmail on a server with this set up.

**Step 1**
Installing PHPFarm

```
yum install gcc libxml2-devel openssl-devel bzip2-devel curl-devel libjpeg-devel     freetype-devel icu libicu-devel gcc-c++ postgresql-devel aspell-devel git -y

$ cd /opt/
$ git clone https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm.git phpfarm
$ cd phpfarm/src/
$ cd /opt/phpfarm/src/
```

For each version of php you want run this. However, If you want custom modules such as mysql support skip this and see the part just below it.

```
$ ./compile.sh 5.3.1
$ ./compile.sh 5.3.3
$ ./compile.sh 5.5.11
```

If you get compile errors, reboot and try./compile.sh 5.3.1 again
This worked for me when I ran into this problem

**MYSQL & Module Support**
Steps for getting MySQL support (and other modules) for custom phpfarm install of php version  5.5.14. These instructions work for any version just rename 5.5.14 to what ever like 5.4.3. You will of course need a mysql server to connect to to make use of the mysql module within php.

These steps need to be completed in this order

**Step  1A**
Ensure you have these paths and the date time is correct I did this as root. You should have the date.timezone you intend to use.

```
cd /opt/phpfarm/src
vi custom-php.ini

date.timezone=America/Halifax
include_path=".:/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-$version/pear/php/"
```

**Step  1B**
Ensure you have these paths and the date time is correct

```
cd /opt/phpfarm/src
vi default-custom-php.ini

date.timezone=America/Halifax
include_path=".:/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-$version/pear/php/"
```

**Step 1C**
 
Pay Special Attention to this line

```
--with-config-file-path=/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.5.11/lib/ \
```

it will need to be adjusted for the version you are working with. As root

```
vi custom-options-5.5.14.sh

#!/bin/bash

#gcov='--enable-gcov'
configoptions="
--disable-debug \
--with-config-file-path=/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.5.11/lib/ \
--enable-short-tags \
--with-pear \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip \
--with-zlib \
--with-gettext \
--enable-pdo \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--enable-cgi \
--enable-json \
--with-curl \
--with-openssl \
--enable-openssl \
--with-mysql \
--enable-mysql \
$gcov"
```

**Step 1D**
 
Now compile as root. Phpfarm will automatically look for a file named custom-options-5.5.14.sh when you compile 5.5.14, or any other version with of course respective version numbers.

```
./compile.sh 5.5.14
```

Later when you check out your web page with the phpinfo(); function, you will see support for these modules and different "Configure Command" text on the page.

---

If these steps are not completed in order you may have to do it again. 
In order to do this again first remove the files from the src folder and the inst folder.

```
rm -rf /opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.5.14

rm -rf /opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.14
```

The rm will remove the folder and the -rf stands for r recursive and f force.
Ref: http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/rm1.html

---

If you have errors check with this site. There are others but I found this one useful.

http://crybit.com/20-common-php-compilation-errors-and-fix-unix/

---

Reference for the mysql and module support

[Issue activating a php extension using PHP Farm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028229/issue-activating-a-php-extension-using-php-farm)

---

**Step 2**
Adding phpfarm to your profiles

add this to the bottom of .bashrc for root and non-root user. The .bashrc file can be found in the users root folder or cd ~/  then ls -all and you should see it.

```
PATH="$PATH:/opt/phpfarm/inst/bin:/opt/phpfarm/inst/current-bin"
```

also execute this in terminal after you have added it to the .bashrc files for root and non-root user

```
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/phpfarm/inst/bin:/opt/phpfarm/inst/current-bin"
```

now exit the terminal and log back in. try this command

```
switch-phpfarm 5.5.11
```

you should be able to switch back and forth between diff php versions

```
[root@test joe]# switch-phpfarm 5.5.11
Setting active PHP version to 5.5.11
PHP 5.5.11 (cli) (built: May 17 2014 22:01:31) (DEBUG)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
[root@test joe]#
```

add the repo for CentOS/RHEL 6, 64 Bit (x86_64):

```
cd /tmp
rpm -Uvh http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

**Step 3**
install the yums

```
yum install php php-cli mod_fastcgi
```

**NOTE**
at this point if you try to run the switch-phpfarm 5.5.11 it wont work properly but thats ok. we will still be able to run multiple websites with different versions of php

**Step 4**
Ensure your cgi-bin is created and files are configured

```
$ cd  /var/www
```

If the cgi-bin isn’t already here create it

```
$ mkdir cgi-bin
```

For each version of php you intend to use make one of these files. Replace the ending with the version number

```
vi /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.5.11
```

**step 5**
Inside the file  php.fastcgi.5.5.11

```
#!/bin/bash
PHPRC="/opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.11/php.ini-development"
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=4
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-cgi-5.5.11
```

The first line

```
PHPRC="/opt/phpfarm/src/php-5.5.11/php.ini-development"
```

Tells you witch php.ini to use this is different in ubuntu. The last line

```
exec /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-cgi-5.5.11
```

also needs to be changed for each particular version. I am not sure what it does but I do know it needs to be changed.

**Step 6**
Enable fastcgi files to be executable for apache:apache user and group

Example 1

```
[root@test joe]# chown apache:apache /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.5.11
[root@test joe]# chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.5.11
```

Example 2

```
[root@test joe]# chown apache:apache /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.3.3
[root@test joe]# chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.3.3
```

Example 3

```
[root@test joe]# chown apache:apache /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.3.1
[root@test joe]# chmod +x /var/www/cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.3.1
```

**Step 7**
Editing the httpd.conf file
Here’s what you need for the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.
First find “NameVirtualHost *:80”  and use this as a starting point.The “#” means the line is commented out. Uncomment this line by deleting the #. it Should now look like this.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

This will allow multiple virtual host to operate on Apache by their "ServerName" in each virtual host reference. I left some lines commented to show you what you can do without. Make sure the bottom of the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf looks like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.com
   #ServerAdmin admin@tecadmin.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test1
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test1">
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
            AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
            Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.5.11
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test2.com
#   ServerAdmin admin@tecadmin.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test2
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test2">
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
            AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
            Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.3.3
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test3.org
#   ServerAdmin admin@tecadmin.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test3
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/test3">
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
            AddHandler php5-fastcgi .php
            Action php5-fastcgi /cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.3.1
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test4.net
#   ServerAdmin admin@tecadmin.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test6
</VirtualHost>
```

**Step 8**
Editing the etc/hosts file 
here is what u need in the etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost test1.com test2.com test3.org test4.net
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

**Step 9**

Now restart your server

```
service httpd restart
```

**Step 10**
Testing
if you add phpinfo() to each of the index.php sites you will notice that all the php versions will be different. also the last one test4.net will go with the default for centos. Also note that test3.org and test4.net are not .com's but will still work. In the future I plan to make a guide for the phpfarm files so you can install with mysql support. This was another issue I ran into. If you notice some errors in this or have difficult making it work, please comment and I will get to it as soon as I can.

Comment: I am at the point where I am running `switch-phpfarm 5.5.11` but it still shows php 5.3.3. Any suggestions?

Comment: figured it out. I already had php installed through yum so I noticed this is expected. Trying to figure out how ot do this without this issue

Comment: I have no idea what causes this, I imagine in has to do with the fact that the main php is run through Apache as normal and not as fastcgi. If you figure it out please let me know and I will add those details for others.

Comment: I changed `yum install php php-cli mod_fastcgi` to be `yum install mod_fastcgi` and I now have no issue. I am still able to `switch-phpfarm` and this also allows me to set my default PHP while only having to specialize installs for other flavors. I did use a special config for compiling my PHP installs before installing them. So far so good, I will let you know if I have any issues. I am configuring a new server this week so this should be a good test for this setup.

Comment: That is very cool. I have some stuff about adding support for mysql in phpfarm.  I hope to get it ready tonight in a raw form. Also I need to add all the specific verion numbers Iam currently working for Apache etc. at Some point I need to figure out how to add modules for different of php in phpfarm. I suspect that last one will be a challenge. Also I should test this for Centos 6.6 and Centos 7.

Comment: I haven't had to install anything problematic yet. I used http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/phpfarm-install-extensions.htm as a reference for installing other extensions. This page shows a config example: http://thejibe.com/blog/14/02/phpfarm I am using CentOS 6.6 currently, not too concerned for 7 yet but I imagine the process is very similar. Also, I used this page to make sure I am installing a secure version of PHP: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/php-install-statistics.html?m=1

Comment: I am also working on adding multiple MySQL instances too. Considering this poses an issue with older PHP installs for an up-to-date MySQL install. I think I'll add my findings as a response to your topic. Hopefully this thread will become a useful resource.

Comment: I think I originally used yum install php because I am running iredmail on my server and that needs the native php from apache. If I had the time to figure out a work around for this I would. Can't wait to read your multiple mysql addition. I edited this page to make it easier to read. I updated the requirements, and now it should be easier to understand for new users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: There, I have put it in the form of a question. Just like Jeopardy!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because... it´s not a question

Comment: Isn't this a question ? How can I get multiple php versions running on Centos 6.5 at the same time?

Comment: Are you trying to write this as a Q&A? It seems like you're trying to answer your own question in a step-by-step process. Some clarification would be great

Comment: I originally asked the question here. When no one answered it I eventually figured it out and answered it. As I got many hits on the original question but no answers I felt it was a good idea to answer the question because clearly, I wasn't the only one interested in an answer.

Comment: I've httpd-2.4.18 version, So anyone try with this version using this method?

Answer (score 1):

Several notices from me:

1. `yum install php php-cli mod_fastcgi` is not correct. mod_php should not be enabled. also `mod_fastcgi` can be installed without external repository using `mod_fcgid`
2. For PHP 5.2 and libxml>=1.2.9 you have to apply this patch [libxml29_compat.patch](http://help.digipower.vn/getattachment.php?data=MjMzfGxpYnhtbDI5X2NvbXBhdC5wYXRjaA%3D%3D)
3. to set php version for all host without mod_php enabled add this to httpd.conf

   ```
   <Directory "/var/www">
       Options All +ExecCGI
       AddHandler php-cgi .php
       Action php-cgi /cgi-bin/php.fastcgi.5.5.18
   </Directory>
   ```
4. when compiling on 64bit systems the compilation fails because of lib64 folder so you should add `--with-libdir=lib64` to configoptions

Comment: yum install php php-cli mod_fastcgi was used with the intention of enabling iredmail without adjusting any iredmail config files. If you aren't using this with iredmail you might want to do it another way. The original guide was done on a 64 bit system. Although I can't speak for php 5.2 as I have never tested it myself