# Issue activating a php extension using PHP Farm

Tags: php, ubuntu, zend-framework, phpfarm

I am implementing a software ([Getsy](https://etsyclone.com/)) that requires PHP 5.4 and ZendGuard 6 ([ZendGuard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/downloads#Linux)).

For the occasion I am using an AWS Instance of Ubuntu 14.04. As Ubuntu 14.04 comes with PHP 5.5+ by default, I needed to install PHP 5.4. To do that I installed PHP Farm.

To change PHP versions among sites I have this cgi-bin script:

```
#!/bin/sh
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=3
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS
exec /opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-cgi-5.4.30
```

For my specific site (site changed for ****), I have this configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/****.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin                 ...@...
        ServerName                  ****
        ServerAlias                 ****
        DocumentRoot                /var/www/****/public_html/
        ErrorLog                    /var/www/****/logs/error.log
        LogLevel                    warn
        CustomLog                   /var/www/****/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                AddHandler php-cgi .php
                Action php-cgi /cgi-bin-php/php-cgi-5.4.30
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So, when I run my site's `phpinfo()` everything is fine and the site is running with PHP 5.4.30.

Now, I need to enable the ZendGuard Loader extension. I download the 64-bit linux version from [here](http://downloads.zend.com/guard/6.0.0/ZendGuardLoader-70429-PHP-5.4-linux-glibc23-x86_64.tar.gz) using the following commands:

```
cd ~
wget http://downloads.zend.com/guard/6.0.0/ZendGuardLoader-70429-PHP-5.4-linux-glibc23-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvf ZendGuardLoader-70429-PHP-5.4-linux-glibc23-x86_64.tar.gz
cd ZendGuardLoader-70429-PHP-5.4-linux-glibc23-x86_64
cd php-5.4.x
mv ZendGuardLoader.so /usr/lib/php5/ZendGuardLoader.so
```

So, afterwards, in order to install PHP 5.4.30 I create the file `custom-options-5.4.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#gcov='--enable-gcov'
configoptions="--disable-debug \
--enable-short-tags \
--with-pear \
--enable-bcmath \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-ftp \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-pcntl \
--enable-soap \
--enable-sockets \
--enable-wddx \
--enable-zip \
--with-zlib \
--with-gettext \
--enable-pdo \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--enable-cgi \
--enable-json \
--with-curl \
--with-gd \
--enable-gd \
--with-openssl \
--enable-openssl \
--with-mysql \
--enable-mysql \
$gcov"
```

I also use a custom php ini file as `custom-php.ini`:

```
include_path=".:/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-$version/pear/php/"
[Zend]
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/ZendGuardLoader.so"
```

Afterwards, in order to compile the PHP version I use this command:

```
cd /opt/phpfarm/src/
./compile 5.4.30
```

So, immediately afterwards I get all the output and php gets installed correctly, but when I check the PHP version in the `/opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-5.4.30 -v` I get this output:

```
PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2014 23:41:33)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

For some reason it's not loading the ZendGuard extension. When I check the `phpinfo()` the ZendGuard doesn't appear at all. When I check the `/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.4.30/lib/php.ini` the `zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/ZendGuardLoader.so"` line is there.

Any ideas why it's not loading the extension or how I could enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apparently everything was working fine but for some reason PHP wasn't reading the php.ini file and none of the changes were reflected. What I did was I deleted the `inst/php-5.4.30` folder and also the `src/php-5.4.30` folder, I revised my `custom-options-5.4.sh` file and I added the following line:

```
--with-config-file-path=/opt/phpfarm/inst/php-5.4.30/lib/ \
```

Afterwards I compiled again, restarted apache2 and everything worked correctly. I hope this can be useful to someone else :).

Ah, and also, now the output of `php -v` looks like this:

```
PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Sep 26 2014 16:13:45)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure with --enable-xdebug:

./configure --with-php-config=/opt/phpfarm/inst/bin/php-config-5.4.16 --enable-xdebug