# Enable extensions in PHP 5.5.2 - phpfarm - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, curl, gd, mcrypt, phpfarm

[Magento Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMAcj.png)

Hello, I want to know how can I enable extensions using phpfarm.

Thanks !

Comment: read this , hope it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028229/issue-activating-a-php-extension-using-php-farm

Answer (score 0):

For extensions shipped with the php core, adjust the `custom-options.sh` file - see https://github.com/cweiske/phpfarm#customization

Example:

```
configoptions="$configoptions --enable-curl"
```