# two different joomla sites under same apache server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, joomla

I have an Apache version 2.4.6 installed on centos 7.3 and php version is 5.4.13.

under this server `/var/www/html/site1` I have installed a joomla 3.5 site.

Until now all is ok.

I need under `/var/www/html/site2` install a joomla 2.5 site that is copied from another server.

I have already migrated the mysql database.

The new site when running have a lot of errors for a lot of plugins.

The site2 joomla o the previous server ran php 5.3 version. I tried with `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php` in `.htaccess` file but nothing.

Please note I haven t install the php 5.3 on new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php` you can change the php version only if this version is already installed in your server. Since you don't have this version installed, it will not work for you. You have 2 options.

1. install these 2 versions of php alongside (which can be quite painful) [multiple php on apache centos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330670/multiple-php-on-apache-centos)
2. migrate the site2 to run in php5.4

I'd go with the second option